# Enable Azure StorageV2 static website (preview) feature using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

Im trying to write an ARM template that creates a storage account with the new static website (preview) feature:

[image]

When I go to the Automation Script blade I don't see any related settings within the ARM template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccounts_spastore_name": {
            "defaultValue": "spastore",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccounts_spastore_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "tags": {
                "purpose": "example"
            },
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "networkAcls": {
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                    "ipRules": [],
                    "defaultAction": "Allow"
                },
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": false,
                "encryption": {
                    "services": {
                        "file": {
                            "enabled": true
                        },
                        "blob": {
                            "enabled": true
                        }
                    },
                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                },
                "accessTier": "Hot"
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I also don't see any related settings within the Azure Resource Explorer. I am aware that I have to use a newer API version as well but I don't know how to enable the feature using an ARM Template?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you can (at least as of today). ARM templates are meant for controlling the `Control Plane` whereas [`Static Websites Settings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-service-properties) feature is exposed as part of `Data Plane` which is accessed by [`Storage Service REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/).

With the announcement of `RBAC` (and Azure AD roles) for Azure Storage, I am seeing some of the operations from Storage Service REST API becoming available in `Storage Resource Provider API`, so my guess is that sooner or later this functionality will be exposed there as well. Then you should be able to configure it through ARM templates.

Comment: That might be the reason. Thanks Gaurav! I will do some further research and accept your answer If I don't find any related ARM setting for that

Comment: Please do. If you find anything, please post that as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can I mention you in my blog article? https://about-azure.com/2018/07/03/angular-6-application-hosted-on-azure-storage-static-website/

Comment: Please go ahead. Thanks!

Comment: Does anybody knows if this is already possible via ARM templates?

Comment: Hugo Barona - looks like not but you can use this approach http://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/03/deploy-automatically-static-website.html

Comment: Just got off call with Microsoft, their suggested method is to use a PowerShell script to enable this feature, post-deployment. It is still not an available option in ARM.

Comment: You can also do it using a deployment script in the template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template

Comment: How do we print the primary endpoint of the blob static website in ARM outputs section?

Answer (score 4):

It is ugly but you can do it with a deployment script in arm/bicep:

```
param deploymentScriptTimestamp string = utcNow()
param indexDocument string = 'index.html'
param errorDocument404Path string = 'error.html'

var storageAccountContributorRoleDefinitionId = subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '17d1049b-9a84-46fb-8f53-869881c3d3ab')

resource managedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
  name: 'DeploymentScript'
  location: location
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
  scope: storageAccount
  name: guid(resourceGroup().id, storageAccountContributorRoleDefinitionId)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: storageAccountContributorRoleDefinitionId
    principalId: managedIdentity.properties.principalId
  }
}

resource deploymentScript 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'deploymentScript'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    roleAssignment
    storageAccount
  ]
  properties: {
    azPowerShellVersion: '3.0'
    scriptContent: '''
param(
    [string] $ResourceGroupName,
    [string] $StorageAccountName,
    [string] $IndexDocument,
    [string] $ErrorDocument404Path)
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
Enable-AzStorageStaticWebsite -Context $ctx -IndexDocument $IndexDocument -ErrorDocument404Path $ErrorDocument404Path
'''
    forceUpdateTag: deploymentScriptTimestamp
    retentionInterval: 'PT4H'
    arguments: '-ResourceGroupName ${resourceGroup().name} -StorageAccountName ${accountName} -IndexDocument ${indexDocument} -ErrorDocument404Path ${errorDocument404Path}'
  }
}
```

see: [azure example for static website, resource templates and scripts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.storage/storage-static-website)

Comment: How do we print the primary endpoint of the blob static website in ARM outputs section?

Comment: Add the following two lines to the end of the script

$DeploymentScriptOutputs = @{}
$DeploymentScriptOutputs['url'] = $storageAccount.PrimaryEndpoints.Web

This will return the primary url, from the deployment script back to the ARM Template for you to use within the rest of you ARM Template.